# couple Solspace Freeform multi-page form questions

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace

I'm using the multi-page function of Freeform Pro for the first time and I have a couple questions.

- is it possible to have a "back to page X" button on other pages of the form that sends someone back to a previous page in the form? If I do it manually, it will take me to that page, but the data previously entered into the fields is gone.
- most of the fields in the form will be required. I setup inline errors and left a field empty to test. The page refreshed and displayed the error successfully, but I lost all the field date previously entered. Can the inline errors be displayed without removing all the data from fields, or will i have to rely on some JS error detection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Freeform's custom field variables such as `{freeform:field:FIELD_NAME}`, returning to a previous page should have its fields populated with previous data since the variable tries to retrieve this data. If your fields are manually-coded in HTML, the data isn't retrievable as easily, although the data should be available using [`{freeform:mp_data:FIELD_NAME}`](https://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/form/#freeform_mp_data_field_name)

This should answer both of your sub-questions. :)

Comment: Thanks, I did have the fields manually coded. I switch that all out for the custom field variables and things are working fine. Thanks again!